# How do i get only the new unique values per group?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'user': ['Michael', 'Michael', 'Lea', 'Michael']})
```

I have a dataframe like this, it is already a result grouped by Month.

```
   Month     user
0      2  Michael
1      2  Michael
2      3      Lea
3      3  Michael
```

What I want is to count the total unique AND the new unique users compared to the month before.

Total is no problem, can just use:

```
df.groupby(['Month'])['user'].nunique()
```

```
Month
2    1
3    2
```

But what I want are only the new unique ones, I do not want to count the ones that already were there in Month 2 when I count in Month 3.

In my minimal example "Lea" is a new user in Month "3", "Michael" is not because he was already user in Month "2". So my expected result would be per month the count of new unique users like this

```
   Month     Unique_Count_New_Users
0      2     1
1      3     1      <- Lea is new compared to February, Michael isn't
```

How can I achieve this in python? Do I need some sort of element wise comparison between the groups?

---

So i edit here to make it more clear: I need compare to all previous month if the user was already there.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                   'user':['Michael', 'Michael', 'Markus', 'Moritz', 'Lea', 
                           'Michael', 'Stefan', 'Dora', 'Erika',
                           'Dora', 'Markus']})
```

```
df
```

```
    Month     user
0       2  Michael
1       2  Michael
2       2   Markus
3       2   Moritz
4       2      Lea
5       3  Michael
6       3   Stefan
7       3     Dora
8       3    Erika
9       4     Dora
10      4   Markus
```

```
df.groupby(['Month'])['user'].nunique()

# Solution

# Sort the dataframe first

df.sort_values(by='month', inplace=True)

# Duplicated trick

(~df['user'].duplicated()).groupby(df['Month']).sum()

# Result

Month
2    4
3    3
4    0
```

Comment: When counting unique users do you need to compare with just the previous month or all the months before the current month?

Comment: I need to compare to all previous month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use

```
(~df['user'].duplicated()).groupby(df['Month']).sum()
```

Demo:

```
>>> df 
   Month     user
0      2  Michael
1      2  Michael
2      3      Lea
3      3  Michael
>>> (~df['user'].duplicated()).groupby(df['Month']).sum()
Month
2    1
3    1
```

I'm assuming that the `'Month'` column is sorted, otherwise the `duplicated` trick won't work.

edit: your exact output can be produced with

```
(~df['user'].duplicated()).groupby(df['Month']).sum().reset_index().rename({'user': 'Unique_Count_New_Users'}, axis=1)
```

Comment: don't i need:

(~df['user'].duplicated()).groupby(df['Month']).sum()

Comment: @steff9488 thanks for the hint, we need to negate the result of `duplicated`, of course.

Comment: With sorting my table first, this is exactly what i need. Thank you! @timgeb

Comment: Ok so this works, but i lack some understanding why this works. Is this because how duplicated works with its default keep='first' parameter?

Comment: @steff9488 yes. If you look at the result of `df['user'].duplicated()`, you will get a `False` for the first occurence of every username. We're negating that result to get `True` instead. Since the `'Month'` column is ordered, this `True` value will correspond to the first month the user is seen. The rest is simply grouping the data by month and then summing up all the `True` values in each group (`True` is treated as `1`, `False` as `0`).